# Tooltip on bokeh violin chart built from seaborn package

Tags: tooltip, bokeh, seaborn, violin-plot

I was trying to use **violin chart** in **Bokeh** but unable to find this type of chart. So, I use **seaborn** library to build the **violin chart** and use it into **bokeh**.

*Code:*

```
import seaborn as sns
from bokeh import mpl
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1,1,1,2], "y":4,5,8,9})
sns.violinplot(x="x", y="y", data=df)
plot = mpl.to_bokeh()
plot.plot_width = 500
plot.plot_height = 300
```

Now, I want to add **tooltip** on **bokeh** converted chart from **seaborn**. I googled a lot but not able to find a way.

Comment: i don't know this, but my guess is that anything constructed with `mpl.to_bokeh()` is going to be pretty limited.

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer possible, at least in this form. The MPL compatibilityin bokeh, including `mpl.to_bokeh()` was deprecated and completely removed some time ago. You might have a look at [Holoviews](http://holoviews.org/) which is a very high level API built on top of Bokeh that I believe just added a Violin plot.